# Get checkbox value in a html form

Tags: php, html

The part of the form this post goes about is this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SOMEVALUE1" value="SOMEVALUE1" class="css-checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="SOMEVALUE2" value="SOMEVALUE2" class="css-checkbox" name="checkbox2" />
```

Now I want to make a PHP/MySQL script that posts every selected value, so if SOMEVALUE1 is selected and the form is posted it puts SOMEVALUE1 in the table, if both values are selected it puts SOMEVALUE1 in the table *and* it puts SOMEVALUE2 in the table.

Summed up: I want to get all values of checked checkboxes

Comment: IDs **must** be unique, and checkbox names should either be distinct or an array.

Comment: And you couldn't find any other questions that answer this? There must be hundreds of them. It should also be shown in most PHP tutorials on working with forms. It seems like you've made absolutely no effort to learn how to do this.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that explain how to do things like this. What have you tried so far and what didn't work? And reiterating what @j08691 said, IDs must be unique.

Comment: @Barmar, I've searched long enough and haven't found a question that answer exactly what I mean

Comment: change checkbox name also

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=php+save+checkbox+value+to+database  135,000 results. You couldn't understand any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `name` from `checkbox` to `checkbox[]`. This will change it from a single value in `$_REQUEST` to an array of values in `$_REQUEST`.